# How to get XML string within JSON field?

Tags: jquery, xml, json, datatables

I would like to get results into jquery datatables via JSON. 
The page is written in JSP.

The table contain a special field with XML string:

```
{ 
  "sEcho": 1, 
  "iTotalRecords": "3800", 
  "iTotalDisplayRecords": "3800", 
  "aaData": [ [ "16.12.2013 14:14:55 GMT", 
                "Unknown", 
                "Unknown", 
                "", 
                "26414321279", 
                "ci1387203295280.36875276@czchols2138_te", 
                "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ExtendedEventContent> <Transport_Failure> <Error>Incomplete data received</Error> <Transport_Error>com.cyclonecommerce.tradingengine.transport.FileNotFoundException: 550 TEST.xml: The system cannot find the file specified. ; command=RETR TEST.xml</Transport_Error> </Transport_Failure> </ExtendedEventContent> ", 
                "" ] ,
               ...
```

datatables initiation script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#failedDetails').dataTable( {
      "bStateSave": true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "./inc_failed_details_json.jsp",
  "aLengthMenu": [[10, 50, 100, -1], [10, 50, 100, "All"]],
      "iDisplayLength": 10,
  "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
 } );
```

} );

I am getting of course error:

> ... JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

The data are gathered from Oracle DB. 
I have tried to use replace for the XML value by:

```
(select replace(max(details), '"', '\"') from cyclone.messageevents where messageoid = m.oid) Details,
```

> > ```
> >  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <ExtendedEventContent> <Reason> <Event>Messaging.Message.Duplicate.Message</Event> </Reason> </ExtendedEventContent> "
> > ```

but with same result.

Exists anybody who can help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert `" "` into `' '` in your `XML field`

i have created jsfiddle to [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w7CgY/)

```
var obj1 = {};
obj1.data = "Name"
obj1.xmlData = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <ExtendedEventContent> <Transport_Failure> <Error>Incomplete data received</Error> <Transport_Error>com.cyclonecommerce.tradingengine.transport.FileNotFoundException: 550 TEST.xml: The system cannot find the file specified. ; command=RETR TEST.xml</Transport_Error> </Transport_Failure> </ExtendedEventContent>"

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.test').html(JSON.stringify(obj1));
});
```

Comment: Thank you Patel. Nice solution.

Even I have resolved that problem by `regexp_replace(to_char(wm_concat(rejectedreason)), '[[:cntrl:]]|\\')` while gathering data from DB I will definitely reuse your solution for another pain-point :)

Thanks again
Regards
Rudo